# Select specific array elements of gremlin query result

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a dataset with products and orders. For a given product (here PRODUCT 2) I want to find the 5 products that were ordered most in combination with PRODUCT 2.

I have managed to query and sort all associated products with their frequency.

```
g.V().has('PRODUCT', 'id', '2').as('a').in('purchased').out('purchased').where(neq('a')).groupCount().order(local).by(values, Order.decr)
```

returns

```
==>[4:3,6:2,7:2,12:2,13:2,14:2,15:2,1:1,3:1,5:1,8:1,9:1,10:1,11:1,16:1,17:1]
```

gremlin gives me an array with all the results, so I cannot use the limit step or range step. How could I select only the first five entries of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `groupCount()` returns a `Map` not an "array". Also, note that you already are using the mechanism to do what you want to do - `Scope.local`. Both `limit()` and `range()` can take a `Scope` so you can do:

```
 g.V().has('PRODUCT', 'id', '2').as('a').
   in('purchased').out('purchased').
   where(neq('a')).
   groupCount().
   order(local).by(values, Order.decr).
   limit(local,5)
```

It's worth remembering that a `Map` is just a collection and can therefore be deconstructed to its item with `unfold()` in which case:

```
 g.V().has('PRODUCT', 'id', '2').as('a').
   in('purchased').out('purchased').
   where(neq('a')).
   groupCount().
   order(local).by(values, Order.decr).
   unfold()
   limit(5)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I understand it much better now.